# Largest and Smallest number ...in 32bit arm Assembly language

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, 32-bit

This is a homework problem I have been struggling with all week.
The Guidelines:
" Write a program that asks the user to enter positive nonzero integer values.  The user enters a -999 to signal the end of the data series.  After all the numbers have been entered, the program should output the largest and smallest numbers entered.

Largest Number:    XXXX

Smallest Number:  XXXX

If a negative value is entered other than -999 the program should stop with an error message.

I would love to use an array, but can't find a way to use an array to store integers that a user has entered.
I realize it may be a mess, but here is the code I've adapted for a previous program:

```
   .global main
.func main

@Starts Program
main: 
    sub sp, sp, #24             @stack
    
    ldr r0, =userPrompt         @calls prompt
    bl printf                   @prints to screen
    ldr r0, =format             @calls format
    mov r1, SP                  @Add Stack to register 1 
    bl scanf
    
    ldr r3, [sp]        @stores user input
    add sp, sp, #16     @restores stack
    mov r5, #0          @Moves 0 into R5

    cmp r3, #0          @Compares r3 to 0
    blt ex              @branches to exception
//  bgt ex2             @branches to exception2 

    
storeValue:
        STR r1, [r4]
        add sp, sp, #24
    
getNum: 
    ldr r0, =userPrompt     @calls prompt
    bl printf               @prints to screen

    ldr r0, =format         @Calls Format
    mov r1, sp              @Add Stack to register 1 
    bl scanf                @Prints to Screen

    ldr r3, [sp]            @stores user input
    add sp, sp, #16         @restores stack
    mov r5, #0              @Moves 0 into R5
    

    cmp r3, #0              @Compares r3 to decimal 0
    blt exception           @branches to excption if r3 = less than 0
    
loop:               @Beginning of loop 
    cmp r4, r3      @Compares r3 to r4 to see if equal
    bgt end         @Greater than Branch 
    
    str r4,[] r4, r4, #1    @increases by 1 
    beq loop        @branch if equal
    blt loop        @branch if less than
    
    
    
@End Program

    mov r7, #1      @syscall 
    swi 0

ex: 
    ldr r0, = exception @calls exception to print(e)    
    bl printf           @prints to screen
    b getNum            @branches to getNum to re-ask for a number
    
LrgNum:
    


.data                                                                   
output:     .asciz  "\n\nLargest Number Entered %d is: %d\n\n\n"  "\n\nSmallest Number Entered %d is: %d\n\n\n"  
usrPrompt:  .asciz  "\n\nEnter positive numbers to compare. To see results enter -199 \t"                        
exception:  .asciz  "\nInvalid Entry. Enter a positive number greater than 0\n\n"                                
format:     .asciz  "%d"                                                                                         
input:      .word 0
blanklines: .asciz "\n\n"
exitcom:    .word  "-199"                                                       
.end
```

Comment: There is no reason to use an array, you can keep a running min/max updated as you read the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For this very specific task, you don’t need an array at all: the minimum and maximum of a sequence can be computed “on-the-fly”, with no need for storing earlier values.

Now I won’t give you assembly code, but I think you already know how to implement all of it.

For the record: storing a sequence of unknown, arbitrarily long length would be much trickier, as you would need to allocate an initial buffer, then increase its capacity each time your buffer is full, by reallocating it with a larger capacity and copying its values. Last, but certainly not least: I am not entirely sure about ARM assembly, but I believe that, to be able to “allocate”, you would have to implement your own small memory manager (i.e., a `malloc` routine).

Comment: For dynamic allocation, you just need to keep track of the original program break (in bss) returned by the first call to `__NR_brk`. The you can simply allocate as needed by subsequent calls to `__NR_brk` keeping track of the new break returned each time. Not really a "memory manager", but more just accounting for where you have moved the break from so it can be restored when done.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Or use `push` inside your loop to build an array on the stack (in reverse order, but that's fine.)  The growth limit is lower than `brk`, but still plenty large for interactive use.  Either way, you have easy contiguous allocation so you don't need to copy on reallocate.  (Doing the same thing with mmap is possible by using the hint address to request pages contiguous with your existing allocation, but if you get a different address you need to just alloc a new larger space and copy.)